# document.createElement('div') fails silently in React constructor

Tags: reactjs, createelement

I am trying to display a form using ReactDOM.createPortal().
It works fine for the first time.
But if I close and try to open again - it does not show.
No error messages - none.
Note "main-win" and the created div are siblings.
Is this the right way to do it??

```
class MyForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            el : document.createElement('div'), 
            divid : Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000)
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.getElementById('main-win').style= "display:none"
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.getElementById('main-win').style= "display:block"  
    }
    handleClose(){
        var element = document.getElementById(this.state.divid)
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
        document.getElementById('main-win').style= "display:block"
    }
    render(){
        return(
              <div id={this.state.divid} className="form-display">
                  <Theform /> // details removed
              </div>
              )
    }
```

}

Comment: There is no need to use portals like this. You can check this [portal example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd) and use state to handle open\close in your component.

Comment: Thanks. I shall give it a another try. The above is based on ideas from this exact example... Thanks for your time!

Comment: The portal example works well for app-root siblings.
I am trying to have the "modal-root" inside the page. On an inner div.
It opens very nice - but only once. later on it fails and I cannot find the reason.

Comment: If it fails it should throw an error, otherwise there is a logic error in your code, for example not using state to control close\open. To help you solve your problem SO community will need [minimum viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the other example in doc about event bubbling.

Comment: This is the answer to my issue: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/272

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above is here https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/272
MyForm is the child and setting it as the link suggests, solved the issue.